# Composer: nothing to install or update

Tags: composer-php

I want install [this](https://github.com/katzgrau/KLogger).
I installed composer, set the environment variable path in w10.
Edit the `composer.json` located in this folder:

> C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\php\PEAR

with this content:

```
{
"name":"amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php",
"description":"AWS SDK for PHP",
"keywords":["aws","amazon","sdk","s3","ec2","dynamodb"],
"type":"library",
"license":"Apache-2.0",
"authors":[
    {
        "name":"Amazon Web Services",
        "homepage":"http://aws.amazon.com"
    }
],
"homepage": "http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/",
"require":{
    "php":">=5.2.0"
},
"autoload":{
    "classmap": [
        "authentication/",
        "extensions/",
        "lib/",
        "services/",
        "utilities/",
        "sdk.class.php"
    ]
}
}
 {
"require": {
    "katzgrau/klogger": "dev-master"
 }
}
```

but when I execute this command in my console:

```
composer require katzgrau/klogger:dev-master
```

I get:

> nothing to install or update

what I did wrong?

Comment: 1. your `composer.json` should be in your projects folder. I think `C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\php\PEAR` is not where you project is located. 2. your `composer.json` does have 2 `require` sections. I think this is not valid. Where does this amazonwebservices part come from?

Comment: Okay now the first problem is fixed. The console display me: `Problem 1: The requested package katzgrau/klogger 1.2.0 could not be found. Potential cause -  A typo in the package - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting see <http....` what is wrong now?

Comment: set `"minimum-stability": "dev"` maybe have a look at the [Composer Documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) too.

Answer (score 2):

You are reusing the composer.json file of "aws-sdk-for-php". 
That is probably not your project. And you are in the wrong folder (PEAR). 
Don't copy and paste `composer.json` files... anyway:

---

1. Create a new project folder
2. then simply run `composer require katzgrau/klogger:1.2.0`

You'll get all dependencies fetched into the vendor folder and a fresh `composer.json` file for your project.